# Why don't RDBMS support array types for columns?

Tags: database, database-design, language-agnostic

Lets take the beaten to death example of a blog engine.

You have the blog, the blog has posts, the posts have tags for organizational purposes. After deciding that tagging problem is not trivial in an RDBMS environment, we go to google for guidance and find the following neat summary of the solutions as the first hit: [designs](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html) and [related benchmarks](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/06/tagsystems-performance-tests.html). However, all of them come at a cost of either performance or complexity. Seems like a NoSQL-like approach of letting you store a list of tags within a column (in NoSQL we can store documents in documents) would solve the problem nicely. Why don't SQLServer/Qracle/MySQL/Postgres/etc. have it then?

At first I thought it might be because of the varying size. But any RDBMS worth noting allows some form of varchar and text (substantial in size). So sizing of the column (and the fact that the same column in different rows would have different size isn't the issue). So instead of storing a blob of text, let us store a list of items of the same type (an array in most languages) in a column. Let us index it for efficient exact searches matches. And at least for all use cases that I have the need for NoSQL DBs would disappear as a necessity (I know a lot of people are harping about scalability, but I don't know/care enough about that, I don't have scalability issue, I have maintenance nightmares). We get simplistic design of our schema (every bit as clean and simple as document in document of NoSQL) and great performance thanks to efficient indexing. Stranger still, that an open source DBs (e.g. Postgres) don't have some sort of patch for this feature. Developers with motivation in the fields seem way to enamored with creating new DBs from scratch, these days.

Am I missing some staggering technical obstacle or are the aforementioned RDBMS vendors just lazy or leaving in the past?

Comment: You said "After deciding that tagging problem is not trivial in an RDBMS environment...". I don't usually work with blogs. What's "that tagging problem"?

Comment: Follow the 'designs' link, it has detailed explanations. Essentially the problem is how to best store tags in a relational DB. My thesis is that relational DB makers (MS, Oracle, OSS, etc.) make it harder than it needs to be, for no good reason other than hubris or malignant intent. Most likely hubris.

Comment: Your thesis is flawed because it presumes that relational database management systems are flawed if they are built to work well with data stored in higher normal forms.  The theoretical underpinnings of RDBMS were established by Codd et al 40 years ago.  It is not hubris to build a product that adheres to its theoretical underpinnings.  There are alternatives to RDBMS if you have data that doesn't fit that model well.  Don't pick on a tool for being good at what it was built for and lousy for something it wasn't built for.

Comment: @Joel Brown I do not believe that what I am proposing goes against those design principles you allude to. When I query to retrieve the value in the column, I'd get back an array as an indivisible whole, how is that different from returning text or int? It's not. But we gain ability to index efficiently for subset search. So I maintain that it is hubris. It was probably too difficult to do 40 years ago, and now they just don't want to improve.

Comment: Considering how trivial it is to handle this problem using ORM tools (fetch a row, get an array with data related to that row from other table(s)) in just about every language since FORTRAN what would be the advantage? And now someone will be compelled to write a FORTRAN ORM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons are historical.

Allowing values of any "collection" type inside a cell in a table, was typically considered a violation of 1NF, as it implied, "by definition", the possibility of "repeating groups" appearing inside a (single row of a) table.

Theory has evolved quite a bit since the early days of SQL, however, and theory currently has it that :

(a) Any type of value, including Array/Set/Collection types, should be allowed in a cell
(b) To be in 1NF, simply means to be relational data.  (But note that SQL tables typically are *NOT* "relational" data in the sense how theory defines the concept.)

Date has written dozens of pages on the subject.  Reading your way through those will provide you with an answer to your question that is far more complete than any answer that can fit in here.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Because that would be non-relational. Most NoSQL databases eschew the sort of relationships that make up a traditional *Relational* Database.

This "task" ("storing an array") can be accomplished in many ways -- XML, JSON, a custom format, or even custom database types, etc. The amount of support (including native type support as mabn pointed out) varies by the RDBMS. For instance, SQL Server provide a fair bit of XML support. However, this generally breaks database normalization (if it is cared about) -- in the case of NoSQL the *baseline* is often that it is not.

The benchmark also only really considers the intersection of *relatively many* tags in a query and it does not show any NoSQL solutions to this problem -- e.g. how would a NoSQL solutions find the results of a query for the intersection n-tags stored in an array?

That is, imagine that an array type *is* used. How long would those same queries take to execute? Without extensive uses of indices and hash-joins, I'd imagine "a very long time".

Happy thinking.

Comment: It most certainly is not non-relational. If storing all tags in a text field is or storing them in a dedicated table is, then so is an array type column. The performance would also not suffer, since without the tags being stored in a blog of text, but separated into individual instances of varchar or text, one can build efficient index for exact search. This is how it is done in a NoSQL DB (I used raven DB in my study) it provides a nice definition, allows for index definiton and is cleanly queriable by LINQ, just like SQLServer would be.

Comment: The NoSQL solution (at least in RavenDB) is essentially “MySQLicious” solution from designs link I've provided, but efficient due to indexed search on individual tags instead of plaintext search on a text blob.

Comment: @Alex K In that case, I am failing to see difference between this 'array type' and a separate table, except that the latter case is explicit (and as the approaches demonstrate, is highly flexible). The difference is then simply that the 'array type' can only be accessed as a value of a specific record? (e.g. not join-able otherwise) I still fail to see how the underlying indexing would be fundamentally different or faster.

Comment: @Alex K If the previous comment of mine is applicable then the question isn't so much of "why aren't array types supported?" but "why are SQL schemas so complex for some 'simple' tasks?" (And a database can get very complex quickly! There are a number of sore-spots in SQL, such as the lack of distributed foreign keys, but I'm not sure this is one. Consider how much of SQL resolves around the DDL.)

Comment: @pst There is a fundamental difference between an array type for column and a table. When I query for a value in that column for some row, I would get an array back, a nice manageable structure and immediately usable. If we take Oracle's solution of having tables in table, when I query I'd get back a table, and I would have to do DB operations without a DB on client side. Folly. And the indexing is fundamentally different: if we store them as text, then we beat plain text search with array index; if going against storing as separate table then array column will beat it since no join.

Comment: @Alex K So the real problem is data-access layer X is not providing a nice array access layer over a set of result records (result of a join between "the item" and "the corresponding array", assume the records are ordered if that is a requirement)? I am still not seeing the "real issue" here. SQL Server (just as an example) provides a fair amount of support for dealing with multiple result-sets as long as they have a static structure.

Answer (score 2):

> Why don't
>   SQLServer/Qracle/MySQL/Postgres/etc.

[They don't?](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm#20425)

Comment: I should have clarified that versions I've worked with do not. Perhaps I should've solicited opinions on whether or not the situation has changed for any of the vendors. Speaking about that link. It is the most dense and incomprehensible explanation of anything in RDBMS realm I've ever read. No wonder I never came across it in my search.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres supports arrays.

It is true that array types are supposed to be a big no no as far as database normalisation forms is concerned but sometimes you have to live dangerously :-)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

You can store a table inside the intersection of a column and a row.  You can do everything you would be able to do with arrays in columns, and more.

Comment: Thats why it fails though. I don't want a table in there, that's complexity and maintenance nightmare down the road.

Comment: having an intersection table is considerably less complex than storing an array in a "row". Access is easier SQL or equvilent is cleaner and more precise. I think the "complexity" involved is in changing from a fixed hierarchical OO way of thinking for the simpler, cleaner, flexible, and more sophisticated "relational" set theory based thinking.

Comment: That is not a correct logic. SQL language is set theoretic (1 dimensional structure). The simplest of tables is 2 dimensional. That's why complexity of queries grows out of control on non-trivial designs of anything that can't be represented in a way that can be mapped onto 1d line (trees can be, and you are lucky if you have them, that's why OO design is beneficial to RDBMS, inheritance tree). That's why flickr's lead DB designer is on record as saying "normalization is for sissies". All in the name of combating the impedance mismatch between query language and storage it queries.

Comment: @James it looks like you completely missed Walter's point.  An "intersection table" typically means an "additional" table.  Walter talks of the "intersection _between a column and a row_".  That is, a cell in the table, a place where the value for that particular column in that particular row is held.  And he means that that value held, can be a "Table value" itself.

Comment: @Alex in relational theory, a relation is a set of n-tuples.  In that sense, a relation is exactly as one-dimensional as any other collection of things can be said to be one-dimensional.  Don't confuse relations with tables, which are _pictures of_ relations.  (Also note that the fact that a relation is a set of _n_-tuples, makes for the claim that relations can be of just any dimension - even including the edge case of "no dimension at all", "zero-dimensional", ...  Which is counter to the common misconception that "relations are flat".)

Comment: I once heard a chief systems programmer proclaim that "high-level languages are for sissies. Real men use only assembler."